# Troubleshooting Logkeys Keylogger Ubuntu 14.04 - Empty log file

Tags: 14.04, log

This is what I am doing.

```
sudo gedit /var/log/logkeys.log
```

Then I would look at my log file to see if it worked and saw that it was blank! Is there any way that I can fix this so I can be able to view my logs?

Answer (score 0):

Did you enter this?

```
logkeys --start --output path/to/logkeys.log
```

Also logkeys may need to be prompted with your correct device id; you can see the procedure to fix it in the docs, all the way down under 'Troubleshooting'

https://github.com/kernc/logkeys#Usage_how-to

Comment: Thanks for your timely response.I tried logkeys --start --output path/to/logkeys.log but it didn't work

Comment: To be clear, make sure you don't actually type 'path/to/', but 'var/log/', in your case.

Comment: If it's the device id, you just type logkeys -d ((device #)) to change the device logkeys is watching.  Possible #'s are 0 -31.  Instructions in the link above.

Comment: Thanks for your  timely response.After spending ample of time I have managed to see something in log file, but logkeys is dumping wrong character.